# Write regex for testing a param is present in URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url, parameters

I have the following reg ex and I am new to this:
`https:\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/.*`

And the strings I am using to test are:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&ec=click&ea=test
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&ea=tes
```

Currently, both strings will pass this check as I am doing `/.*` at the end of the regex, but what I want is this should check for `ec=click` param only and the ONLY the first test string should pass (`https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&ec=click&ea=test`)... does anyone know how I can do this?

Link to playground: https://regex101.com/r/mIjGjD/1

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

`https:\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/(.*)&ec=click(.*)`

I guess this is what you want

Comment: The first two `.` should be `\.` and if `ec=click` may be the first parameter `[?&]` rather than `&` would be needed. The capturing groups `()` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work. Notice that I add a map function in order to get all possible matches in an array of urls

```js
const urls = [
"https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&ec=click&ea=test",
"https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&ea=test"
];

const reg = /https:\/\/www\.google-analytics\.com\/.*&ec=click.*/;

const matches = urls.map(url => url.match(reg) || []).flat();

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: The first two `.` should be `\.` and how about word boundaries `\b` around or `[?&]` before the `ec=click`?

Comment: @MikeM thanks for the corrections. Yes, text points always should be with \ before